# Stretching an image in GIMP

Tags: gimp

[image: pogchamp turning to pogomega]

How can I stretch an image like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Warp Transform tool in GIMP

It's located here on the toolbar shown below, or you can press <kbd>W</kbd> to select it. Then just paint with it to move and warp the pixels.  You can change the size of the tool using the <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys. When you have finished hit <kbd>Return / Enter</kbd> to commit the warp.

[image]

It works best if you don't go too crazy with the tool, otherwise you will get a lot of blurring.

Example before and after:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't use gimp but from a quick google and youtube search I think the tool you are looking for is the **Warp transform tool**.

[this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ0De7d14mk) demonstrate how to use this tool (i think it's in Dutch but you can still get the gist)